# How can I remove this database design anomaly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I am designing a database schema for my project, where I seem to have been stuck by a strange vision-block (in the sense that, I have never had this issue before since its virtually too easy to resolve, except in this particular case - for me)

I have an entity `homes`, that can have various `facilities`.
So, I have declared a model: `FacilitySet` that looks like:

```
id, home_id, parking, electricity
```

As you can see, each row of `facility_sets` table corresponds to a Home.

But, in my opinion, it would make a whole lot more sense to me, if I could say: a home has_many facilities, rather than a home has_one facility_set. This, also, provides an advantage that I can simply say: @home.facilities, rather than @home.facility_set

The real problem is that I can not understand how to structure the `facilities` table in the database, so that I can simply declare:

```
class Home << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facilities
  ..
end
```

and access facilities like: `@home.facilities`

I am, currently, doing:

```
class Home << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :facility_set
  ..
end
```

and access facilities like: `@home.facility_set`, which really makes me feel I am doing something horribly wrong!! :~)

Its early morning here, and I would really really appreciate any `ray-of-ho(m)e` for me.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class InitSchema < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :homes do |t|
      t.integer :id, null: false
      # ...
    end

    create_table :facilities do |t|
      t.integer :id, null: false
      t.integer :home_id, null: false
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :value, null: false
    end
  end
end

class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facilities
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home
end
```

Now use the facilities name and values field to store things like parking, electricity, etc. You may want to create a FacilityType class that has_many Facilities, and keep parking, electricity, etc., in there.

Comment: Thank you, for this :) Any issues with this approach, you can think of, over FacilitySets? Is this the better approach?

Comment: @Stpoc. one nice thing is that you can add new facility types without changing the schema. Another is all the benefits of data normalization, e.g. making it easier to query homes with a particular set of facilities.